# Python is overwriting my list

Tags: python, list, overwrite

I am newly trying to work with Python. I have built a 4th-Dimensional array; the first three dimension define a location in a world-space, and the fourth refers to nodes that might belong to that space. A node is a pre-defined class that I have made.
At first every entry in the list is set as None, and later I add values in as necessary. My issue is that whenever I add these values it seems to overwrite every entry to be equal to the last one included.
Here is the relevant excerpt from the calling module:

```
import Node
myList = [[] for i in range(4)]
xDim = yDim = zDim = 0
def main():
   return 1

def setDimensions(x, y, z):
   global myList, xDim, yDim, zDim
   xDim = x
   yDim = y
   zDim = z
   myList = [ [ [ [ None for i in range(12)] for j in range(z) ] for k in range(y) ] for l in range(x) ]

def process(x, y, z, data):
   global myList
   for i in range(12):
       a = int(data[i])
       if a != 0:
           myList[x][y][z][i] = Node.Node()
           myList[x][y][z][i].setType(a, i, x, y, z)   
   print(myList[0][0][0][3].getX(), myList[0][0][0][3].getY(), myList[0][0][0][3].getZ())
```

and here is the excerpt from the Node class, contained in the module Node.py:

```
Type = xCoord = yCoord = zCoord = 0
class Node():
def main():
    return 1
def getX(self):
    global xCoord
    return xCoord

def getY(self):
    global yCoord
    return yCoord

def getZ(self):
    global zCoord
    return zCoord    

def setType(self, color, i, x, y, z):
    global xCoord, yCoord, zCoord
    xCoord = x
    yCoord = y
    zCoord = z
```

When I run print at the end of the process method I expect to see 0, 0, 0 each time. Instead, though, I see:

0 0 0

0 0 1

0 0 2

.

.

.

3 3 3

And further tests have confirmed that each time I create a new node and add it to my list it seems to not only take the position in the list that I want, but also overwrites every previous list entry with itself. What am I missing?

Comment: Your nodes are different, but they getX return the same global variable, so you get your result

Comment: As a side note, unless you're doing this specifically to learn about multidimensional lists, you should strongly consider using [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org). (And even if you _are_ doing this to learn about multidimensional lists, you may want to try to build something that acts like a NumPy 4D array as one of your first learning exercises…)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please note that Arrays and Lists are two totally different concepts, which just look similar. If you want real Arrays take abamerts suggestion into consideration.

Comment: Thanks all three of you. I have heard about NumPy before. I guess I really ought to give it a closer look, though. I've got everything working now after abarnet's solution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with your lists, which you appear to be doing correctly—you have a whole bunch of separate `Node` instances.

The problem is that `Node` uses global variables instead of attributes, so all of those separate `Node` instances will return the exact same thing from `node.getX()`—the value of the global variable `xCoord`.

The solution is to just not do that:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self):
        self.xCoord, self.yCoord, self.zCoord = 0, 0, 0
    def main():
        return 1
    def getX(self):
        return self.xCoord

    def getY(self):
        return self.yCoord

    def getZ(self):
        return self.zCoord    

    def setType(self, color, i, x, y, z):
        self.xCoord = x
        self.yCoord = y
        self.zCoord = z
```

However, it's worth noting that there's almost never a good reason to have "getter and setter" methods like this in Python. Just write code that accesses `node.xCoord` instead of `node.getX()`, and you can eliminate the methods entirely.

Comment: Ah, brilliant, this fixed things up splendidly. And as you might imagine, this is very helpful beyond the specific issue. Obviously this is a key concept. So global variables apply to the whole package and self variables cover the entire class. Anything else will only exist in it's method. If I want to make use of a global or class-wide variable I ought to either declare at the start of the method that these variables are global, or else explicitly refer to them as self.variableName. That sound about right? This really does explain a lot of things I was running into elsewhere in my code.

Comment: @user1693804: Almost. `self` variables apply to _each instance of the class_, not to the class itself, which it the key. (There are class variables for that, but you rarely need them.) Otherwise, exactly right: `global` variables (and `nonlocal` closure variables in Python 3) you declare at the top of the method, class and instance variables you refer to with the class name or `self`, and everything else is local. And usually you only want instance and local variables.